# Overload operator<< (unsigned char typedef as byte)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I want to overload (hijack?) `ostream` and `basic_ostream<unsigned char>` so that it stops attempting to display an octet (unsigned char) as a printable character.

I've been living with `cout` and friends putting smiley faces on the screen for far too long. And I'm tired of working around with casts: `hex << int(0xFF & b) << ...`.

Is it possible to override the standard behavior? I've tried both template and non-template overrides. They compile, but do not appear to be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there already is a

```
template<class charT, class traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>& 
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>&, charT);
```

in `namespace std`. Since `basic_ostream<>` is also in this namespace, ADL picks it up when you output an `unsigned char`. Adding your own overload might make calling the operator ambiguous, or your overload will silently be ignored.

But even if it would work, it would be brittle, because forgetting one include might subtly alter the meaning of the code without any diagnostic from the compiler.
And there's more: Every maintenance programmer looking at such code will assume the standard operator is called (and never think of adding an include when he adds another output statement to the code).
In short, ***it might be best to add a function*** doing what you want to do.

A reasonable semantic alternative to that might be to add a stream manipulator that invokes the output format you want. I'm not sure if that's technically possible, though.

Comment: @sbi: in spite of your explanation of how it should not work, overloading works nicely with MSVC, and compiles with Comeau Online, so I just posted it as answer. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: Nobody doubted that it _compiles_, the question is which one it calls. And I wouldn't trust VC with that. I could be wrong, though, and VC could be right.

Comment: I took the time to post a complete answer. I started when Als was the only answer to the question, so I can't say I saw the last sentence of this answer (adding a manipulator) before I wrote my answer. Took a good deal of hunting to remember the right way to do it, too. I've written a *lot* of answers with zero or one vote in the past like this, where I posted after most of the SO community has moved on to other questions. It's just how things are.

Comment: @sbi: also works nicely with g++ 4.4.1. so, methinks you're wrong about this. of course, i wouldn't have posted it if i wasn't fairly sure, but this way i can get Someone Else to do the heavy work of looking up the relevant clauses in the standard... <g>

Comment: TBF I wouldn't trust MSVS with it either. Regardless, the point regarding maintainability is, for me, paramount.

Comment: BTW, @sbi, when I comment on something, and the answerer edits the answer in response, I don't get anything in my StackExchange "inbox", so I might not know that a "please correct this" comment needs to be removed. It's a design flaw in the inbox, with no simple solution, IMHO.

Comment: @Mike: I was too lazy to research into the manipulator idea and was, at first, glad you fleshed that out and meant to upvote it. I never thought your were plagiarizing.

Comment: @Mike: That was all explained already, and Tomalak had already seen the fixed posting and even replied with a smiley, before he edited his comment and went into rant mode, calling me childish for improving my answer iteratively.

Comment: @Alf: You might be right. I hope I didn't make the impression I was sure about that. But that still leaves the remaining of my answer intact: you shouldn't do this even if it works _syntactically_.

Comment: @Alf: I already changed my answer. I no longer say this won't compile, I say it might (which is the extend of my knowledge), but even if it does compile, it's wrong, because... That seems appropriate to me.

Comment: @sbi: Didn't mean to imply plagiarism, just that when someone uses the "quick post then huge edit" strategy, I could wind up duplicating another's answer without knowing, and look like a plagiarizer.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, I can understand this. FWIW, I upvoted your comment to make it more visible. OTOH, a look at my answer's history shows that I added the manipulator idea as an afterthought. I can't bring myself to see anything bad in adding ideas to an answer as an afterthought.

Answer (score 5):

Luc is correct.

A quicker alternative to your current approach — if you don't mind decimal output — is to promote the char to `int`:

```
unsigned char c = '!';
os << +c;
```

I don't see how this would be taxing!

Comment: Could explain how this is parsed ? It does not seem obvious that it even compiles (even though it does: http://ideone.com/TzV3N).

Comment: @Matthieu Can you parse `int i = -j;`? What about `int i = +j;`? (That's a unary `operator+`.)

Comment: @Matthieu: Why would it not? That's unary `+`, and an integral promotion is performed. You may read all about it in `[2003: 5.3.1/6]`.

Comment: @Luc: I know, however I am still convinced that it is far from being obvious. Since the `+` is redundant, it is rarely (if ever) used apart from DSLs.

Comment: @Matthieu, Tomalak is just using implicit conversion to `int`, via unary `+` operator. That is, the automatic "promotion" of types in expressions. I prefer to write `c+0` instead of `+c`, because as your question illustrates, the latter can be a bit too subtle.

Comment: @Matthieu: It's not "redundant" at all.

Comment: @Alf: IMO that one is just as subtle. It's no more clear that a conversion is performed: if `+c` looks "redundant" to somebody then surely adding zero will look just as redundant to the same person.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ah, you have graduated to JavaScript expert :-)

Comment: From what I understood @Matthieu's problem wasn't that he didn't understand it, but that he considered it too subtle. ICBWT. I must admit he has a point there, this `+` is easily overlooked, especially when imagining maintenance of a large application hiding this trick somewhere. I still maintain that simply adding a function for this might be better.

Comment: @sbi: Yep, and we weighed up the subtleties of this approach compared to the stated alternatives. ICBWT?

Comment: @Tomalak: why not simply use `int(c)` ? It is, indeed, 4 more characters, but not having the reader digging into integral promotion rules to understand the code make it so much more accessible!

Comment: @Matthieu: You're welcome to. As somebody who knows the language and thus does not find `+c` confusing, I choose `+c`.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>       // std::char_traits

typedef unsigned char       UChar;
typedef UChar               Byte;

typedef std::char_traits<char>      CharTraits;
typedef std::char_traits<wchar_t>   WCharTraits;

typedef std::basic_ostream< char, CharTraits >      CharOStream;
typedef std::basic_ostream< wchar_t, WCharTraits >  WCharOStream;

CharOStream& operator<<( CharOStream& stream, UChar v )
{
    return stream << v+0;
}

int main()
{
    char const      c   = 'c';
    UChar const     u   = 'u';

    std::cout << c << '\n' << u << std::endl;
}
```

This works nicely with MSVC 10.0 and MinGW g++ 4.4.1, and it compiles cleanly with Comeau Online, so I believe it's formally OK.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Why do you drag `std::char_traits` in there, @Alf? Wouldn't `std::basic_ostream<char>` work just as well?

Comment: Also, while this might work syntactically, it does have the semantic disadvantages I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Als is right that what you're asking for isn't going to happen.

The best you can do is to [write your own IO manipulator (`iomanip`) to do the magic for you.](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/WritingStreamManipulators.html) In this case, you need a function that takes an `unsigned char` (though I'd *strongly* recommend using `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>`).

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ostream>

class asHex
{
public:
    asHex(uint8_t theByte): value(theByte) {}
    void operator()(std::ostream &out) const 
        { std::ios::fmtflags oldFlags = out.flags; out << std::hex 
              << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase << theByte; 
          out.flags(oldFlags); }
private:
    uint8_t theByte;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, asHex number)
{
    number(out); return out;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
cout << asHex(myByte);
```

You can add constructors to `asHex` or even make it a template class to support 16, 32, and other bit counts.

(Yes, I know `<stdint.h>` is not an official C++ header, but I'd rather have its definitions in the global namespace instead of `std::` without having to do a `using namespace std;` which dumps *everything* in the global namespace.)

Comment: If you do that, you don't need the whole manipulator machinery, messing around with the original stream. Just make a function `std::string asHex(unsigned char)` and be done. Much easier.

Comment: That turns into a question of "Which is better, creating a temporary `std::string` or a temporary object which does not touch the heap?" which I can't answer without usage context. I still prefer the class-based approach in my answer since it doesn't involve heap allocation and has a better chance of getting optimized by the compiler.

Comment: We're talking output here, usually to a terminal or into a file. I doubt that the allocation of a `std::string` is relevant for the common use case of this. Anyhow, if it is, just return a `struct foo { char[2] string; };` instead and overload `<<` for it. That doesn't change what I wrote a bit. Your method, OTOH, has the disadvantage that it manipulates the mode of the stream. I can never remember which of these manipulators are permanent, but I believe at least some of them are. That's bad, because users of your manipulator need to remember to reset stream modes they didn't set themselves.

Comment: So the `oldFlags = out.flags;` ... `out.flags(oldFlags);` doesn't sufficiently save and restore stream state? Didn't know that. That's been one of my pet peeves with iostream: it's really hard to modularize output and not botch things up. I still think formatting and I/O should have been split from each other: one set of APIs to make a formatted `std::string` and another to send that string somewhere. Like Python's `str.format()`.

Comment: To my utmost embarrassment I simply overlooked that part of your code. OTOH, I really don't know whether this is sufficient. It might well be, or it might not, and absent of J. Kanze, D. Kühl, or a thorough study of Langer/Kreft, I don't know whom to trust in their opinion on the matter. (Who really knows about `pword`/`iword` stuff?) I also think the iostreams lib isn't as good as a language's single, general input/output library ought to be, and the missing ability to safe a stream's whole state is but one problem.

Answer (score 1):

Due to ADL the standard `operator<<` will be called. Try to explicitly qualify your call:

```
::operator<<(os, 42);
```

Comment: @Jan Now he can call his operator.

Comment: Lol, yes. It's a solution. Of course, it's not a very good one, but it is one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the behavior of `std::cout` directly.  It would be too error-prone if any dev code can change the behavior of the standard library used by other code.

You **can** create your own class that emulates the behavior of `std::cout` and use that object instead.

```
class SpecialCout
{
    template <typename T>
    friend SpecialCout& operator<< ( SpecialCout const& scout, T const &t )
    {
        // Do any adjustments to t here, or decide to return early.

        std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }

};

extern SpecialCout scout;
```

Comment: Why restrict yourself to `std::cout`?